# Android Fetch Json

Tags: android, json, parsing

im sorry but im new at android programming, so this may seem like a very stupid question.

i've established connection to my JSON data, but i need to only fetch the data i need, and not all unnecessary data. My Json looks like this:

> data":[{"id":1,"temperature":"21.375","humidity":"28"}

Here i only need id: 1, temperature: 21.375 and humidity: 28

to establish connection i have following method:

```
private class jsonConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String username = "websiteUsername";
        String password = "websitePassword";
        String credentials = username + ":" + password;

        String sensorID = "1";
        String api = "api";
        String websiteURL = "https://" + credentials + "@website.com" + "/" + sensorID + "/" + api;

        String credBase64 = Base64.encodeToString( credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT ).replace( "\n", "" );

        try {

            URL url = new URL( websiteURL );

            System.out.println( url );
            System.out.println( credentials );
            System.out.println( websiteURL );

            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String( encodeBase64URLSafeString( credentials.getBytes() ) );

            connection.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", basicAuth );
            connection.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Language", "en-US" );
            connection.setUseCaches( false );
            connection.setDoInput( true );
            connection.setDoOutput( true );
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( stream ) );

            //StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog( MainActivity.this );
        pd.setMessage( "Please wait" );
        pd.setCancelable( false );
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute( result );
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
            ScrollingMovementMethod());
            System.out.println( data );
            json_string = data;
            System.out.println( "json_string: " + json_string );
        }
    }
```

i imagine i have to do something like this, but i'm not sure how to continue.

```
        try {

        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject( data );
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray( "data" );

        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject( 0 );

        int idName = finalObject.getInt( "id" );
        int tempName = finalObject.getInt( "temperature" );
        int humName = finalObject.getInt( "humidity" );
        String batName = finalObject.getString( "battery" );
        String modeName = finalObject.getString( "mode" );
        String dateName = finalObject.getString( "date_time" );
        String timeName = finalObject.getString( "date_time" );
        String luxName = finalObject.getString( "lux" );

        System.out.println( idName + tempName + humName + batName + modeName + dateName + timeName + luxName );

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have a suspicion that it should not be data inside the parameter, but perhaps something else, and maybe that would fix it?

> ```
>     JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject( data );
> ```

Comment: use volley library instead to get json responses from a server, its gonna be lot easier than this https://www.chrisblunt.com/android-getting-started-with-volley/

Comment: your json is not correct, paste your json here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: You can try **Gson** lib for maping json into object, it is super easy just try it. Start from [here](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. Changing to volley means that i have so spend more time on establishing connection, and it took a lot of time just to establish this connection. It's closed with basicAuth, so i expect it too be very difficult with volley as well and i dont have that amount of time. T

Comment: Data is not formatted right here. The String is a lot longer with a lot more parameters, i just narrowed it down to simplify it. Thats why it's formatted right

Comment: I'll try to use Gson, as it seems like i can continue with my current codes. Again thanks for the fast responses